# Cannot accept marketplace conditions for Azure Batch: "Allocation failed due to marketplace purchase eligibilty"

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-batch, azure-batch-account

I keep getting this error in my Azure batch account: "Allocation failed due to marketplace purchase". My pool allocation is set to "User subscription". I have tried multiple things already, but without success.

I followed the steps from this blog: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/azure-batch-pool-resizing-failed-allocation-failed-due-to/ba-p/2794640

The weird thing is that the following indeed seems to indicate an issue:

```
Get-AzMarketplaceTerms -Publisher 'microsoft-azure-batch' -Product 'ubuntu-server-container' -Name '20-04-lts' 

Name      Product Publisher             Accepted Signature PrivacyPolicyLink
----      ------- ---------             -------- --------- -----------------
20-04-lts         microsoft-azure-batch
```

The indicated next step raises an Exception:

```
Get-AzMarketplaceTerms -Publisher 'microsoft-azure-batch' -Product 'ubuntu-server-container' -Name '20-04-lts' | Set-AzMarketplaceTerms -Accept 
Exception: /usr/local/share/powershell/Modules/Az.MarketplaceOrdering/2.0.0/exports/ProxyCmdletDefinitions.ps1:537
Line |
 537 |          $steppablePipeline.Begin($PSCmdlet)
     |          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Name' because it is an empty string.
```

Therefore I tried the following, which looks as though it works:

```
Set-AzMarketplaceTerms -Publisher 'microsoft-azure-batch' -Product 'ubuntu-server-container' -Name '20-04-lts' -Accept
Name      Product                 Publisher             Accepted Signature
----      -------                 ---------             -------- ---------                                                         
20-04-lts ubuntu-server-container microsoft-azure-batch True    ...
```

However, when I rerun the Get-AzMarketplaceTerms command directly after it, nothing has changed, and most importantly I still get the error in the Batch account.

I also tried to accept using the azure cli, also without success..

```
az vm image terms accept --offer ubuntu-server-container --publisher microsoft-azure-batch --sku 20-04-lts
```

The above does seem to work as

```
az term show --product ubuntu-server-container --plan 20-04-lts --publisher microsoft-azure-batch
{
  "accepted": true,
  "id": "..",
  "licenseTextLink": "",
  "marketplaceTermsLink": "",
  "name": "20-04-lts",
  "plan": "20-04-lts",
  "privacyPolicyLink": "https://privacy.microsoft.com/privacystatement",
  "product": "ubuntu-server-container",
  "publisher": "microsoft-azure-batch",
  "retrieveDatetime": "2023-01-24T15:18:01.7673435Z",
  "signature": ".."
  "systemData": {
    "createdAt": "2023-01-24T15:18:01.814201+00:00",
    "createdBy": "..",
    "createdByType": "ManagedIdentity",
    "lastModifiedAt": "2023-01-24T15:18:01.814201+00:00",
    "lastModifiedBy": "2387a668-4176-44f4-8d08-4c689b1af0ba",
    "lastModifiedByType": "ManagedIdentity"
  },
  "type": "Microsoft.MarketplaceOrdering/offertypes"
}
```

Is there anything else I can do or what I'm missing here? Any help is really appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment I got the results successfully like below.***

I have created an azure batch account with pool allocation mode as a user subscription like the below:

[image]

I was able to create a batch pool with Ubuntu and canonical images available by default in my Subscription. I tried assigning another Publisher with a Windows server and was able to get it in Portal:-

In my case, In batch pool windows server as not show in the pool publisher like below:

[image]

When I try to add a virtual machine configuration publisher as a windows server in windows PowerShell ISE(Run as administrator) It executes successfully like below :

```
Get-AzMarketplaceTerms -Publisher 'microsoftwindowsserver' -Product 'windowsserver' -Name '2019-datacenter-core-smalldisk'
```

[image]

Now, Go to batch account -> pool -> Add

You will be able to see the windows server like below and add it.

[image]

Make sure to add your user as ***owner, contributor*** and **`Microsoft azure batch`** Rbac role assignment.